# Добавить время записи в проекте на django

Tags: django, django-admin

Делаю проект парикмахерской на django, который изучать я начал недавно.
Я хочу к каждому парикмахеру добавить время его работы, чтобы это выглядело, как на портале госуслуг
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я создал класс Master

```
class Master(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(u'Мастер',max_length=155, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
descriptions = models.TextField(u'Описание',blank=True, null=True, default=None)
short_descriptions = models.TextField(u'Стрижки',blank=True, null=True, default=None)
position = models.CharField(u'Должность',max_length=155,blank=True, null=True, default=None);
category = models.ForeignKey(MasterCategory,blank=True, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
is_active = models.BooleanField(u'Активность',default=True)
haircut = models.ForeignKey(Haircut,blank=True, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
date = models.DateTimeField(u'Дата и время',default=timezone.now)
```

Так же класс, где должно быть указано время работы

```
class DateMaster(models.Model):
#is_active = models.BooleanField(u'Активность',default=True)
name = models.CharField(u'Мастер',max_length=155, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
date = models.DateTimeField(u'Дата и время',default=timezone.now)
```

Этот класс в admin добавлен так:

```
class DateMasterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = [field.name for field in DateMaster._meta.fields]
class Meta:
    model = DateMaster

admin.site.register(DateMaster, DateMasterAdmin)
```

Но в админ панеле можно добавить только одно время к парикмахеру
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А на сайте у меня пока так, но я хочу, чтобы вылазило только доступное время
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В самом проекте более менее всё хорошо.
Как мне добиться нужного результата?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно привязать **DateMaster** к **Master** через **foreign key**. В вашем случае: если у мастеров будет одинаковое **name** - то не будет возможности определить к какому мастеру относится расписание.

```
class DateMaster(models.Model):
    master = models.ForeignKey(Master, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(u'Дата и время',default=timezone.now)
```

Также после перепривязки у вас появится возможность на странице изменения **мастера** видеть, изменять, а также добавлять сразу несколько расписаний к одному мастеру. Сделать это можно с помощью **inline-ов** Вот тут описано как с ними работать и примеры реализации:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#using-generic-relations-as-an-inline
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748059/add-inline-model-to-django-admin-site